# Removing duplicate array items from array with filtering in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of items:

```
[
  ["20180629", "14:49", "google", "iOS", "Safari", "1"], 
  ["20180629", "12:22", "google", "Android", "Chrome", "2"],
  ["20180629", "17:20", "google", "iOS", "Safari", "1"], 
  ["20180629", "16:30", "(direct)", "iOS", "Safari", "1"], 
  ["20180629", "09:29", "(direct)", "Android", "Chrome", "2"]
]
```

I need to remove duplicate sub-arrays that have all the same items, except for the first two (timecodes). I narrowed my code down to this:

```
exclude_from_filter = [0,1]


array.each_with_index.map do |array, index|
  array.reject.with_index { |e,i| exclude_from_filter.include? i }
end.uniq!
```

Which removes timecodes and then removes duplicate items:

```
[
  ["google", "iOS", "Safari", "1"], 
  ["google", "Android", "Chrome", "2"], 
  ["(direct)", "iOS", "Safari", "1"], 
  ["(direct)", "Android", "Chrome", "2"]
]
```

However instead I would like to get rid of duplicate items, leaving one unique value intact:

```
[
  ["20180629", "14:49", "google", "iOS", "Safari", "1"], 
  ["20180629", "12:22", "google", "Android", "Chrome", "2"],
  ["20180629", "16:30", "(direct)", "iOS", "Safari", "1"], 
  ["20180629", "09:29", "(direct)", "Android", "Chrome", "2"]
]
```

And this is where I'm completely lost

Comment: Do you need indexes or you want to simply remove duplicates? You can do the latter without the former.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible but the answer below shows it can be done. Will rephrase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to remove the duplicates based on last 4 values, use [`uniq`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/uniq) with a block:

```
ary.uniq { |e| e[2..5] }
 => [["20180629", "14:49", "google", "iOS", "Safari", "1"],
     ["20180629", "12:22", "google", "Android", "Chrome", "2"],
     ["20180629", "16:30", "(direct)", "iOS", "Safari", "1"],
     ["20180629", "09:29", "(direct)", "Android", "Chrome", "2"]]
```

Or, to remove them based on all values except first two, do:

```
ary.uniq { |e| e[2..-1] }
```

which can also be written as (Sergio's suggestion):

```
ary.uniq { |date, time, *rest| rest }
```

Comment: Or, without binding to the max length of the array: `ary.uniq { |e| e[2..-1] }` or `ary.uniq {|date, time, *rest| rest }`

Comment: Did just that. First part. :P

Comment: I wish the block form was named `uniq_by` to be consistent with sort_by/group_by and other similar methods.